# .npmrc registry settings is not used by npm install

Tags: jenkins, npm

I working behind a proxy and therefore I use a local npm registry in nexus.
I have an .npmrc config with the registry settings in jenkins:

```
/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs-default/bin/node "/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs-default/bin/npm" config get registry
https://nexus/repository/npm-all/
```

When I want to run npm install I get the following error:

```
/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs-default/bin/node "/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs-default/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/ariya/esprima.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection refused
npm ERR! github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection refused
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-29T13_46_39_199Z-debug.log
```

Why it want to connect to github.com instead of nexus? It is second run of npm install, the first install downloads some packages from nexus but when it want to download ariya/esprima it stops with the same error.

My package.json: (it is an old build)

```
{
  "name": "my-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autonumeric": "^1.9.39",
    "bootbox": "^4.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.4.1",
    "bootstrap-tour": "^0.10.1",
    "chalk": "^1.0.0",
    "file-sync-cmp": "^0.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.4.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-auto-install": "^0.2.4",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-replace": "^0.10.2",
    "grunt-ts": "^4.2.0",
    "grunt-tsd": "^0.1.0",
    "i18next": "^1.9.0",
    "i18next-client": "^1.9.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery.cookie": "^1.4.1",
    "jquery.scrollto": "^2.1.1",
    "knockout": "^3.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "qunit": "^0.7.6",
    "require": "^2.4.18",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.18",
    "typeahead.js": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: I haven't solved it yet. But now I use gitlab-ci instead of Jenkins.